# Use PHP Array to make dynamic background image

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wrote a script that I want to use to dynamically change the background of a `<div>` based on the city a user is located.  A users city is displayed in variable `$city = 'New York';`.

I have an array in PHP which handles the cities and the images associated:

```
$cities = array(
    "Boston" => array(
            'name' => 'Boston',
            'bg' => 'bs.png'
    ),                                
    "New York" => array(
            'name' => 'New York',
            'bg' => 'ny.png'
    ),
    "Denver" => array(
            'name' => 'Denver',
            'states'    => 'CO', 'WY', 'NE'
    ),
);
```

I'm having trouble writing the if statement that will recognize the city and pulling it into a `<style>` tag.  This is what I wrote, but it does not work at all:

```
if ($city === in_array($city, $cities)) {
                echo '<style>
                    .header {
                        background: url(img/'.$cities['bg'].') no-repeat center center scroll;
                        -webkit-background-size: cover;
                        -moz-background-size: cover;
                        background-size: cover;
                        -o-background-size: cover;
                    }
                    </style>';
            } else {
                echo '<style>
                    .header {
                        background: url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
                        -webkit-background-size: cover;
                        -moz-background-size: cover;
                        background-size: cover;
                        -o-background-size: cover;
                    }
                    </style>';
            }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$cities['bg']` will always be undefined. You need to ensure that it is set. You can use `isset()` to only have to do one condition check:

```
<?php
$cities = array(
    "Boston" => array(
            'name' => 'Boston',
            'bg' => 'bs.png'
    ),                                
    "New York" => array(
            'name' => 'New York',
            'bg' => 'ny.png'
    ),
    "Denver" => array(
            'name' => 'Denver',
            'states'    => 'CO', 'WY', 'NE'
    ),
);

$city = 'New York';

$bg = 'bg.jpg';

if ( isset($cities[$city]['bg']) ){
    $bg = $cities[$city]['bg'];
}

echo <<<EOD
    <style>
    .header {
        background: url(img/{$bg}) no-repeat center center scroll;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
    }
    </style>
EOD;
```

Comment: using `isset()` will check to see if it exists then you can use: `$cities[$city]['bg']` to retrieve the value

Answer (score 4):

The [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function returns a boolean, so you don't need a comparison check. Just use the following conditional:

```
if (in_array($city, $cities)) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried both `array_search()` and `in_array` I'm having a problem with the if statement comparison displaying the image if it exists..